# Renaming phrase in all git repository commits (in submodules)

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

How can I rename a phrase for all previous commits in my git submodules?

```
phrase1 to phrase2
```

My phrase is found in .pack files. (I shortened the hex .pack names):

```
$ grep -rnw . -e 'phrase1'
Binary file ./.git/modules/folder1/objects/pack/pack-6170d.pack matches
Binary file ./.git/modules/folder2/modules/objects/pack/pack-934ef.pack matches
Binary file ./.git/modules/folder2/objects/1b/2eeaa matches
Binary file ./.git/modules/folder2/objects/1e/92b8b matches
Binary file ./.git/objects/54/fcce26 matches
```

I tried running BFG on the repo but I get this output:

```
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar -rt expression_file.txt /my_repo/
...
BFG aborting: No refs to update - no dirty commits found??
...
```

And I tried running BFG with the "--no-blob-protection" argument but I get the same output:

```
...
BFG aborting: No refs to update - no dirty commits found??
...
```

My expression_file.txt has this format:

```
phrase1 ==> phrase2
```

I looked into using "git filter branch" but I am not sure what command to give it to make it rewrite these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer to the `git filter-branch` part of the question.
Here is how you can use it to replace `phrase1` with `phrase2` in all `.txt` files :

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter '
    find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i 's/phrase1/phrase2/g' {} +
' --prune-empty --all
```

Be aware that it can be very time conumming. The `--all` option will perform the replacement in all branches.